# What's the difference between if(varName) and if(varName!=NULL)?

Tags: c, performance, variables, if-statement, null

What's the difference between this:

```
if( varName != NULL ){
  // Do something
}
```

And:

```
if( varName ){
 // Do something
}
```

I mean, is there a difference in terms of process speed? Or is only a better performance?

PD: I'm working with C.

Comment: There's no difference

Comment: The best way to answer this question is to compile with the `-S` option, and then look at the resulting assembly. With optimizations off, there may be a difference, but with optimizations enabled, the assembly code should be identical.

Comment: This is a matter of taste, I like `if (varName != NULL)`. Some like `if (varName)` and you did something that I consider really ugly `if(_something_)` the `_` being a white space looks horrible. Anyway, this question should be closed.

Comment: Depends on the type of `varName`

Comment: @iharob It's ugly for you, and i know it's your opinion and I respect it, but for me, is more confortable. And why "this question should be closed"? I mean, 
It isn't that this platform helps to find solution for the people that has problem with coding or programming? If you want closing this question because you don't consider the white space into the if-statement doesn't mean that the question should closed.

Comment: @4386427: The validity of this code might depend on the type of `varName`. But under the assumption that the code is valid, there's no difference.

Comment: @NicolasMozo I think it will ultimately be an opinion based answer. But, since the question is what is the difference, there might actually be a good answer for it and there was.

Comment: @AnT No idea where you are heading with that comment. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39808702/4386427

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in case of performance, but the difference of *intent*  might be significant. Assuming that `NULL` macro is defined as `(void *) 0`, this code:

```
if( varName != NULL ) {
   // Do something
}
```

enforces that `varName` must be a *pointer* object. For instance, the following code would issue an error message:

```
int varName = 0;
if ( varName != NULL ) {
    // Do something
}
```

> error: comparison between pointer and integer

Hence, this practice might be considered as sort of *defensive programming*, though its value is rather discussable, as both forms are equally idiomatic.

Comment: And it does make the code more readable. When looking through code and you see the comparison with `NULL` you know the type is a pointer not an integral type, without finding the variable's declaration.

Comment: @Weather Vane: A questionable benefit, somewhat similar to the habit of casting the result of `malloc`. Proponents of the latter also often claim that it helps them to "know the type without finding the declaration". In reality "knowing the type" is a proverbial crutch that C developers often need to be able "walk".  I'd say that good programming practices call for type-agnostic code. Yes, even in C. It is more readable. Developers just have to learn to read and understand such type-agnostic code without having to rely on the exact type information, have to learn to walk without crutches.

Comment: @AnT your analogy with casting `malloc` is not at all the same. It's a [straw man argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man), along with your intimation that I cannot walk without crutches.